# Facebook fb:app_id Meta Tag Not Detected Despite Correct Setup

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to implement Facebook Open Graph meta tags on my website to enable better sharing on social media. Specifically, I've included the fb:app_id meta tag as follows:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="699589688344148">
```

I've also set up a Facebook app with the corresponding App ID and associated it with my website. However, when I try to share a link from my site on Facebook, the Sharing Debugger reports that the fb:app_id property is missing.

I've double-checked the following:

1. The meta tag is placed in the  section of my HTML document.
2. The App ID in the meta tag matches the one in my Facebook App settings.
3. The website URL in my Facebook App settings also matches the actual URL of my website.

Despite all these checks, Facebook seems unable to detect the fb:app_id property. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Is there something I might be missing in the setup process?